# END (extended negatively dependent) implies pairwise END

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n \}$ be a sequence of random variables satisfying: for each positive integer $n$ there is some $M>0$ such that
$$
P(X_1  \leq x_1,  \ldots, X_n  \leq x_n) \leq M P(X_1 \leq x_1) \ldots P(X_n  \leq x_n)
$$ 
and
$$
P(X_1  > x_1, \ldots, X_n  > x_n) \leq M P(X_1 > x_1) \ldots P(X_n  > x_n)
$$
for all $x_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ (that is, $\{X_n \}$ is extended negatively dependent).  I'm trying to show
$$
P(X_i > x_i, X_j  > x_j) \leq M P(X_i > x_i) P(X_j  > x_j)
$$ 
for all $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. Any hint would be welcome.

Comment: What does "END" mean here?

Comment: extended negatively dependent.

Comment: Thanks - please add this to the question. The title is unreadable otherwise.